# Using Interface in Protractor test

Tags: node.js, typescript, protractor

I am new to Typescript and Protractor. I have reusable code in different classes. In my test class rather than importing all library classes separately I just want to import just one class/interface that will inherit all my reusable code.
When I use an interface that inherits my classes in Protractor class I get following error at runtime: **Cannot read property 'keyText' of undefined**
Here is my code snippet.

```
    export class textInputLibrary {
    async keyText(element, text)
    {
    //my implementation 
    }
    
    }
    
    export class listItemLibrary{
    async selectDropdownValues(element, textToSelect)
    {
    //my implementation 
    }
    
    }

//These classes are extended in my interface
    export interface library extends checkboxLibrary, elementsLibrary, listItemLibrary, textInputLibrary {
    }

//Interface is imported into my Protractor test class:

    import {library} from "../library/library";
    describe('angularjs homepage', async function() {
        it('should greet the named user', async function() {
          await browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
            let yourName: ElementFinder = await element(by.model('yourName'));        
            let library: library;
            await library.keyText(yourName,"Test123");
        });
      });
```

Comment: `let library: library;` library is undefined. You've given it a type, but no value.

Comment: do you not need to create an instance?

Comment: I tried let Library: librabry = new library(); Still it gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is limitation in TypeScript for interface as states in the below link:
"The ICustomer interface has a significant restriction—you can only use it with classes that extend the same class the interface extended (in this case, that’s the Customer class)."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/january/typescript-understanding-typescript

So to use I my interface I also need to extend the classes in my Test. However, I can only extend one class. Where as my interface extends multiple classes.